# How to partition input lines of file by content, sort, group, and write to output

Tags: python

I have the following result of a diff command between two projects:

```
Only in xyz/666/aaazzz/000999/include: zerp.x
Files abc/666/aaazzz/000999/ggg.ddd.aus and xyz/666/aaazzz/000999/ggg.ddd.aus differ
Only in abc/666/aaazzz/000999: vuvuvu
```

I'd like to write a python script to partition this output as follows,

**Only in xyz:**

*666/aaazzz/000999/include: zerp.x*

**Shared but different:**

*xyz/666/aaazzz/000999/ggg.ddd.aus*

**Only in abc:**

*666/aaazzz/000999: vuvuvu*

I imagine that it could be done by regex, because the lines will always look like that, it's the result of the command:

```
diff --brief -r project1/ project2/
```

but I'm not sure how to construct such a python script, how should it look like?

Comment: Before you build too much into using diff off the cmd line in python, you might want to check out Python's [batteries included](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/AzKKTk/2) works, but is not entirely robust:

```
import re
text = "Only in xyz/666/aaazzz/000999/include: zerp.x\nFiles abc/666/aaazzz/000999/ggg.ddd.aus and xyz/666/aaazzz/000999/ggg.ddd.aus differ\nOnly in abc/666/aaazzz/000999: vuvuvu\n"

p = re.compile(r'([^\/]+)(.+)\nFiles\s.+\s(.+)\sdiffer\n([^\/]+)(.+)')
m = p.match(text)

print(m.group(1)+ ":")
print(m.group(2))
print("Shared but different:")
print(m.group(3))
print(m.group(4) + ":")
print(m.group(5))
```

Result:

```
Only in xyz:
/666/aaazzz/000999/include: zerp.x
Shared but different:
xyz/666/aaazzz/000999/ggg.ddd.aus
Only in abc:
/666/aaazzz/000999: vuvuvu
```

I'd need more examples and edge cases to make it better. It could also be better done on a per line basis (E.g. break up the regex where I've used `\n`).

Apart from being beastly, the only possibly confusing part of the regex is `([^\/]+)` - which captures all characters EXCEPT for `/`, so it can capture the file names (`xyz` and `abc`).